# Why my server is causing two Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers on Express with Nignx Proxy?

Tags: node.js, curl, express, nginx, proxy

I'm building an Express application in Node.js. And I'm turning cors on in express by doing this.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

// some configuration

/**
 * Add cors
 */
app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24
}));
```

We also have Nginx as a proxy which we also have this to allow cross-origin.

```
add_header    Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

It's working fine and I got this response back.

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: max-age=300
< Date: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 00:36:06 GMT
< Expires: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 00:41:06 GMT
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Length: 35
< Connection: keep-alive
```

But when I fire a curl command with origin

```
curl -svo /dev/null http://someurl -H "origin: my.local"
```

I got this response back.

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: my.local
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: max-age=300
< Date: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 00:36:17 GMT
< Expires: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 00:41:17 GMT
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Length: 35
< Connection: keep-alive
```

which it adds two `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which is going to block any request.

Comment: may be remove origin:true or set it false in cors js

Comment: So you meant turn the cors off in Express and leave it on in Nginx?

Comment: yes, worth a try I think

Comment: I tried deleting from Express but I still see double headers.